# Google-like Calculator Program for Windows

Tags: windows, calculator

I love using Google for quick back-of-the-envelope calculations. For instance, if I want to know the approximate weight of a carbon-12 ion with charge state 4, I search for

```
12 u -4*electron mass in u
```

and get the answer 11.9978057 atomic mass units. More complex things, such as the cyclotron frequency of this ion in some magnetic field, are just as easy:

```
1/(2*pi)*4* (elementary charge)/(12 u - 4*(electron mass)) * 5.1125 Tesla
```

This returns the correct answer 26.174171 MHz. The fact that I can enter `12u - 4*(electron mass)` and Google converts the units on the fly, is really helpful to me. WolframAlpha can do even more, but Google is a lot quicker and does not ask for a subscription after my nth query.

As an offline solution, I used a Matlab script in which I had most constants defined, but Matlab takes 30 sec to 1 min to start up, which is frustrating. Mathematica is not much faster to start up, either. Also, for technical reasons I have to use network licenses, so these programs are not offline solutions anymore. I switched to Excel (which loads quite fast), where I have a sheet that used named ranges. This is semi-convenient, but it just feels *wrong*.

Is there any lightweight Windows program that provides this functionality offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Units) program that was originally developed for UNIX. There is a [native Windows port](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/units.htm) that is based on version 1.87 (2008). The current version of the UNIX tool is 2.01 (2012).

Units was originally designed to do simple unit conversion, but it also supports evaluating mathematical expressions. It requires you to specify the unit of the output and gives you two lines as a result: The result that you want is the first line, the second line is the inverse of the result.

This program has three major shortcomings when compared to the Google math expression evaluation:

1. You have to know the unit that you want to get in advance. (I don't always know it, and sometimes I just don't care. Often this unit is "1", as for the result of the calculation sin(pi).)
2. It does not tell you how it interpreted the units that you entered. Google always returns a parsed version of the input string, so that you can see where Google misunderstood you.
3. It is quite strict when it comes to variable names. Multi-word names are not permitted, so `electron mass` is called `electronmass` (`m_e` also works).

The installer.exe is easy enough to use, but on my Windows XP machine it did not set the path variables of the command line correctly. I set up a simple shortcut on my Desktop that points to: `C:\Programs\GnuWin32\bin\units.exe`.

Overall, Units is a nice and quick calculator that starts up a few thousand times faster than Matlab or Mathematica - but the user interface has some shortcomings.